# How to make a function to reduce repetitive codes in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract a name of drugs from df['Text'] series if a suffix from df['Stem'] matches the suffix of the name of drugs.

```
print (df['Text'])

Text
1/1/11 (USA) neoadjuvant arimidex
1/2/11 radafaxine + cisplatin.
1/3/11 abc letrozole

print (df['Stem'])

Stem
dex 
zole
platin
axine
amivir
arit
```

Desired output would be:

```
Drugs
arimidex
radafaxine, cisplatin
letrozole
```

Here's what I have done to extract and create a new series 'Drugs':

```
df['dex'] = df['Text'].str.extract(r"(\w+dex)", expand=False)
df['platin'] = df['Text'].str.extract(r"(\w+platin)", expand=False)
df['xine'] = df['Text'].str.extract(r"(\w+xine)", expand=False)
df['zole'] = df['Text'].str.extract(r"(\w+zole)", expand=False)

df['drugs'] = df[df.columns[2:6]].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)
df = df.drop(df.columns[2:6], axis=1)

df
Text                                 Stem      Drugs
1/1/11 (USA) neoadjuvant arimidex    dex       arimidex
1/2/11 radafaxine + cisplatin.       zole      radafaxine, cisplatin
1/3/11 abc letrozole                 platin    letrozole
NaN                                  axine     NaN
NaN                                  amivir    NaN
NaN                                  arit      NaN
```

However, it is repetitive and I would like to create a function that can iterate through 'Text', match the drug name that contains the suffix, and extract it. I am wondering if there is a Pandas way of doing this. Thank you in advance.

***UPDATE***:
AS per MaxU's advice, I have created a new dataframe that resembles the original data.

```
print (df['Text_Long'])

Text_Long
2/1/14 (JK) DOCETAXEL, PYPHAMIDE
2/10/14 (JK) NITROZOLE
2/12/14-4/15/14 30MV PHOTONS TO LT arm,  JC/WE 500JC IN 25OP
2/22/12 (Kansas/HEM)- NEOADJUVANT KITOTERE, DRYMYCIN, KITOXAN
4/11/11-11/24/11 (JK) CYCLOPHOSPHAMIDE, FLUOROURACIL
4/14/14  (CONN) GEMZAR + OPR.  11/25/14  (CONN) OPR.
4/12/12-10/2/12-KT-RIGHT ARM-5020 NYG, 24 PRESSURE
JK DRUG therapy: aritrozole
NITROZOLE STARTED ON 1/11/12 PER ADVICE
KFC X 2
maritinib & fosclitaxel.
Urioxifen
10/2/12 NEOADJUVANT FLOMIDEX
10/29/12 YUMYCIN, KITOXAN, TACXOL
11/11/14 (JK) GOODZOLE
2/12/12  (CONN)  petbine + pastlatin.
4/2014  (CONN)  Continue PSCORE for 2 cycles.
2/2015 to 5/2015 OSF (Stinson)  XRT
5/19/10-2/21/10 HEMYCIN AND BASKIXAN
5/2/12-5/12/12 1000NY/20FL/30MT/OT A2-A9
2/2015  OPC (JK)  DRUG THERAPY`print(stem)
```

Here's theExcel file consisting of suffix list on Github:
[Link](https://github.com/comprocho/sample_data_stackoverflow/blob/master/suffix.xlsx)

Again, thank you so much for your help and advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have the following DF:

```
In [92]: drugs_stem
Out[93]:
     Stem
0     dex
1    zole
2  platin
3   axine
4  amivir
5    arit
```

and:

```
In [93]: df
Out[93]:
                                Text
0  1/1/11 (USA) neoadjuvant arimidex
1     1/2/11 radafaxine + cisplatin.
2               1/3/11 abc letrozole
```

you can do the following:

```
In [94]: pat = r'\b(\w*(?:{})\w*)\b'.format(drugs_suff.Stem.str.cat(sep='|'))

In [95]: df['Drugs'] = df.Text.str.extractall(pat, flags=re.I).unstack() \
                         .apply(lambda x:', '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)

In [96]: df
Out[96]:
                                Text                  Drugs
0  1/1/11 (USA) neoadjuvant arimidex               arimidex
1     1/2/11 radafaxine + cisplatin.  radafaxine, cisplatin
2               1/3/11 abc letrozole              letrozole
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [25]: %paste
drugs_stem = pd.Series(suffix)
pat = r'\b(\w*(?:{})\w*)\b'.format(drugs_stem.str.cat(sep='|'))
df['Drugs'] = df.Text_Long.str.lower().str.extractall(pat).unstack() \
                .apply(lambda x:', '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
## -- End pasted text --

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
                                            Text_Long                                Drugs
0                    2/1/14 (JK) DOCETAXEL, PYPHAMIDE                            docetaxel
1                              2/10/14 (JK) NITROZOLE                            nitrozole
2   2/12/14-4/15/14 30MV PHOTONS TO LT arm,  JC/WE...                                  NaN
3   2/22/12 (Kansas/HEM)- NEOADJUVANT KITOTERE, DR...                    drymycin, kitoxan
4   4/11/11-11/24/11 (JK) CYCLOPHOSPHAMIDE, FLUORO...                         fluorouracil
5   4/14/14  (CONN) GEMZAR + OPR.  11/25/14  (CONN...                           conn, conn
6   4/12/12-10/2/12-KT-RIGHT ARM-5020 NYG, 24 PRES...                                  NaN
7                         JK DRUG therapy: aritrozole                           aritrozole
8             NITROZOLE STARTED ON 1/11/12 PER ADVICE                   nitrozole, started
9                                             KFC X 2                                  NaN
10                           maritinib & fosclitaxel.               maritinib, fosclitaxel
11                                          Urioxifen                            urioxifen
12                       10/2/12 NEOADJUVANT FLOMIDEX                                  NaN
13                  10/29/12 YUMYCIN, KITOXAN, TACXOL             yumycin, kitoxan, tacxol
14                             11/11/14 (JK) GOODZOLE                                  NaN
15              2/12/12  (CONN)  petbine + pastlatin.                      conn, pastlatin
16      4/2014  (CONN)  Continue PSCORE for 2 cycles.  conn, continue, pscore, for, cycles
17                2/2015 to 5/2015 OSF (Stinson)  XRT                                  NaN
18               5/19/10-2/21/10 HEMYCIN AND BASKIXAN                              hemycin
19           5/2/12-5/12/12 1000NY/20FL/30MT/OT A2-A9                                  NaN
20                     2/2015  OPC (JK)  DRUG THERAPY                                  NaN
```

**NOTE:** this solution has been tested using Pandas 0.19.2 - you might have problems with Pandas versions < 0.19.0 ([a few bugs were fixed in `extractall()` function in Pandas 0.19.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0190))

Comment: I received the following error message: AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 10 columns.

Comment: @comprocho, i'm afraid i would need a __reproducible__ sample data set in order to debug it

Comment: I have updated the original post. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @comprocho, do you have multi-line values as well?

Comment: @comprocho, `KFC X 2` - is it the whole value in the cell?

Comment: @comprocho, please see UPDATE

Comment: @comprocho, what is your Pandas version?

Comment: It is '0.18.1'.

Comment: @comprocho, ok, i see... There were a few bugs in `extractall()`, which were fixed in Pandas 0.19.x. I'd suggest you to update your Pandas version

Comment: You're awesome! Everything is looking good after a version update to 19.2. Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: @comprocho, glad i could help :-)